# Add background solid fill to Altair graph

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I like Altair a lot for making graphs in Python. As a tribute, I wanted to regenerate the Economist graph(s) in ["Mistakes, we’ve drawn a few"](https://medium.economist.com/mistakes-weve-drawn-a-few-8cdd8a42d368):
[image]
This is the code of a first shot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

 df = pd.read_csv('http://infographics.economist.com/databank/Economist_corbyn.csv').dropna()

 bars = alt.Chart(df, title="Average number of likes per Facebook post").mark_bar().
    encode(
        y=alt.Y('Page:O', axis=alt.Axis(title=''),
        sort=alt.EncodingSortField(
           field="Average number of likes per Facebook post 2016:Q",  # The field to use for the sort
           op="sum",  # The operation to run on the field prior to sorting
           order="ascending"  # The order to sort in
       )),
       color=alt.value("#116EA1"),
       x=alt.X("Average number of likes per Facebook post 2016:Q", 
       axis=alt.Axis(title='Average number of likes per Facebook post')),
)


text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3,  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar,
).encode(
    text='Average number of likes per Facebook post 2016:Q'
)

(bars+text).configure_title(fontSize=14)
```

[image]

Four questions:

1. How can I fill the background with the solid color ##D9E9F0 ?
2. How to make the first line pop out (by adding box over the bold label
   'Jeremy Corbyn') ?
3. Can I add the light gray copyright notice in the lower left
   corner with the new Altair text layer possibilities in Version 3 ?
   If so, how to do that ?
4. How can I put the xticks on top of the graph ?

Thanks for help !

UPDATE with answers for (1) and (4) from [jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2937831/jakevdp) and [aberna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4213630/aberna):

```
df['x'] = df['Average number of likes per Facebook post 2016']/1000.0
bars = alt.Chart(
    df, title="Average number of likes per Facebook post ('000)"
).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('Page:O', axis=alt.Axis(title=''),
           sort=alt.EncodingSortField(
            field="Average number of likes per Facebook post 2016:Q",  # The field to use for the sort
            op="sum",  # The operation to run on the field prior to sorting
            order="ascending"  # The order to sort in
        )),
    color=alt.value("#116EA1"),
    x=alt.X("x:Q", 
            axis=alt.Axis(title='', orient="top"),
            scale=alt.Scale(round=True, domain=[0,5])),
)

bars.configure_title(fontSize=14).configure(background='#D9E9F0')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Answering one of your questions: you can add a background using `configure(background="colorname")`. For example:

```
(bars+text).configure_title(fontSize=14).configure(background='#DDEEFF')
```

[image]

Comment: So easy ! Sorry that I could not find it myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Slightly buried away but there (had to double check myself) - https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html#config-chart

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your question number 4 you need to use the `orient="top"` parameter in the     alt.Axis.

```
axis=alt.Axis(title='Average number of likes per Facebook post',orient="top"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. We're getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of answering question number 2. Not the highlighting of the bar but highlighting the labels through conditional font styles.

```
label_style = {
    "condition": [{"test" : "datum.value == 'Jeremy Corbyn'", "value": "bold"}],
    "value": "italic"
}

...

y=alt.Y("Page:N", axis=alt.Axis(title="", labelFontStyle=label_style))
```

[image: Bar chart showing average number of likes per Facebook post with one bold label highlighting Jeremy Corbyn]

Comment: Yes, Thx fror your answer. More concise:
axis=alt.Axis(labelFontSize=14, labelFontStyle=alt.condition('datum.value == "Jeremy Corbyn"', alt.value('bold'), alt.value('italic'))

Comment: Good point! I copied the longer version from my own code where I had more than one highlight with different styles.