# Interactively changing Altair mark text: possibility for background color?

Tags: python, text, interactive, altair

As part of a larger composite figure I have a chart displaying an image, which is accompanied by a `mark_text` chart, which puts the title of the image on the side of it. It is interactive such that clicking in the image will exchange it for another one and also change the text.

Both, the image and the text are just placed on top what was there before. For the images that is no problem in my case, but the texts look ugly and can't be read.

So I would like to either "flush" the display when toggling what gets displayed or add a background color to the text (e.g. white) so the the old text beneath is no longer visible.

Here is an example with random images that resembles my setup

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

image_df = pd.DataFrame({'textfield': 'Here is a title   ','image_1': 'https://heise.cloudimg.io/width/610/q85.png-lossy-85.webp-lossy-85.foil1/_www-heise-de_/imgs/18/2/8/5/7/2/2/9/1-PIA23764-RoverNamePlateonMars-08be0e819a018e5e.png', 'IMAGE_2': 'https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Perseverance-landing-body-image-1.png'}, index=[0])

imageSelector = alt.selection_single(fields=['key'], init={'key': 'image_1'}) 

Img = alt.Chart(image_df).transform_fold(
    ['image_1', 'IMAGE_2']
).mark_image(
    width=400,
    height=300
).encode(
    url = 'value:N'
).add_selection(
    imageSelector
).transform_filter(
    imageSelector
)

ImageTitle = alt.Chart(image_df).transform_fold(
    ['image_1', 'IMAGE_2']
).mark_text(
    dy=-220,
    angle=270,
    size=12
).encode(
    text='label:N'
).transform_calculate(
    label='datum.textfield + "(" + datum.key + ")"'
).transform_filter(
    imageSelector
)

fullImg = Img + ImageTitle
fullImg
```

[image]

To toggle the images, currently one needs to do alternate double-click (i.e. reset selection) and single click (set selection), which is also not the best experience, but works for now. Any hints how this could be improved are appreciated as well. Only, I don't want to add click-able selectors outside the image like radio buttons, the click-to-change action should happen inside the image chart.

To make the texts readable I have tried adding `.configure(background='white')` to the text chart (as described here: [Add background solid fill to Altair graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401706/add-background-solid-fill-to-altair-graph)) but it is not possible, as it is part of a layered chart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to highlight the background of the text via a CSS-like property and the workarounds I can think of are not applicable in this scenario. For example, I tried adding a rectangle mark behind it but it doesn't work with the double click. The reason is that double clicking technically doesn't toggle between the images, it resets to the default view which is everything on top of each other (if you set `empty='none'` in the selector, you will see that double click instead clears the image).

To actually toggle between the images, you need to click an image to show and hide it, e.g since your images are slightly different size you can first double click to show both and then click the small non-overlapping strip at the bottom to hide one of the images, and click the rest of the image to hide the other. So if you only will have two images and are OK with them being slightly different size you can use this approach. You can disable this by setting `nearest=True` in the selector, which make you always select the nearest images instead of unselect and image when you miss a click (which is what happens now I believe)

If you change your mind regarding having a widget, the most intuitive way to  switch between image would be to add e.g. a dropdown below the image by changing the selection code to:

```
imageSelector = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['key'], init={'key': 'image_1'},
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=['image_1', 'IMAGE_2']))
```

Comment: I have now made an upload of my actual figure, to better explain the needs. It can be found at https://doi.org/10.5072/zenodo.742924

Comment: thx @joelostblom. Clicking the small overlap was only possible as my toy images were not the same size, which is not the case in my real images. Also a widget is not practical because I want to toggle the images quickly without moving the mouse and clicking in specific locations. Maybe it could be done with a keyboard event?

Short explanation on the uploaded figure:
An image pair (bottom right) is selected by clicking any of the tiles in the heatmaps (top left) and then toggles by doubleclick / singleclick in the image as I described above.

Hints for image title improvements welcome!

Comment: sorry, I think the DOI link above is not working yet. Use this one instead: https://sandbox.zenodo.org/record/742924

Comment: @roble Hmm, I am not sure if that is possible, but you can try setting the `on` parameter in the selection to any of [these values](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/#types). For exampe, `'mouseover'` creates a different effect. There is also a `'keydown'` value, but  I am not sure sure how you would bind it to a key, you might want to ask a new question specifically about this and tag it with `vega` and `vega-lite`. [This discussion might also be helpful](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1830)