# Modify background color of mark_text()

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I am using Altair to display a choropleth map. When trying to add labels to the map using mark_text(), I am unable to change the background color of these text boxes. I am following the code example on the London Tube Lines [listed on the Altair website](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/london_tube.html):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

boroughs = alt.topo_feature(data.londonBoroughs.url, 'boroughs')
centroids = data.londonCentroids.url

background = alt.Chart(boroughs).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='white',
    strokeWidth=2
).encode(
    color=alt.value('#eee'),
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=500
)

labels = alt.Chart(centroids).mark_text().encode(
    longitude='cx:Q',
    latitude='cy:Q',
    text='bLabel:N',
    size=alt.value(8),
    opacity=alt.value(0.6)
).transform_calculate(
    "bLabel", "indexof (datum.name,' ') > 0  ? substring(datum.name,0,indexof(datum.name, ' ')) : datum.name"
)

background + labels
```

In principle, setting a background color for a text box should be possible in Vega Lite, as shown [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfd0oAmSTClRtJEEGOAg0AG1QAIAmAA53AF0vECYkKHMyMwZZb2sATzhBQTYDJWQTc0NMfJwrdEw4AA83JXVi62c8trlMAGUaAC96gEYABjGUlxVvGllNQJtmt0X1Irz0FCUauusARwY7TDo-GlIPTyA).

Grateful for any hint.

Comment: Have you tried passing the fill option to `mark_text`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the fill option changes the font color, not the background of the text box.

Comment: In both cases, I can change the font color, `color=alt.value('blue')`,`fill=alt.value('red')`, but there is no parameter to change the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer to a similar question, does this answer your question?

**Interactively changing Altair mark text: possibility for background color?**

> I don't think there is a way to highlight the background of the text
> via a CSS-like property and the workarounds I can think of are not
> applicable in this scenario. For example, I tried adding a rectangle
> mark behind it but it doesn't work with the double click. [...]

You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389330/10381546)

Comment: maybe also with `mark_square()`, in case that's more appropriate for your purpose?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solutions works when using `mark_square()` and `mark_circle()`. However, `mark_rect()` does not accept longitude/latitude as parameters to place the rect on a map.

Comment: Just to give you an impression of how it looks like:
http://h2888712.stratoserver.net:8080/#daily-prices

The circles unfortunately cover a large part of the smaller zones in the map. But a background for the label is needed to ensure readability of the text.

Comment: @pruefsumme could you elaborate a bit on the link you shared about the European energy market? Graphs in there are exactly what I want, specifically the mouse over texts, with the pretty backgrounds (and even the little arrows beside the text box). I don't know how to do that in Altair, and I don't really know what the link shared by roble is talking about. Could you share a bit of code that got the text boxes (backgrounds) working?

Comment: Altair is only used for the map. 

For the other graphs I switched to plotly, where the mouseover text & background can be customized more easily.